# Nested if else inside .each iteration

Tags: ruby, nested

I'm wondering if this makes sense or if the syntax is wrong and basically if this is acceptable. I wanted to nest an if/else condition within my iteration of the array.

```
def change_numbers(first_array, second_array)
  second_array.each do |index|

    if first_array[index] == 0
      first_array[index] = 1
    else
      first_array[index] = 0
    end

  end
end
```

The array is a simple (binary) array and will only consist of 0s and 1s and I want to use the second array's elements as the indices of the first array that I am going to change.

Example:

```
first_array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
second_array = [3, 5, 7]
```

Result:

```
first_array = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this, although you may want to check if the index in the `first_array` exists.

Comment: assuming that it is defined, is this an acceptable method of doing this? Or is there an alternative to doing what I want. Sorry, Im just learning the basics right now and I appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm sure there are other ways that don't involve an if/else, but this is an acceptable method.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an if/else you can do:

```
second_array.each do |index|
  first_array[index] = (first_array[index] + 1) % 2
end
```

Comment: thanks!! I would have never gone about it this way but this is really helpful!!

Comment: or `(first_array[index] - 1) .abs`

Answer (score 2):

A [bit-wise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR):

```
ar = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
indices = [3, 5, 7]

indices.each{|i| ar[i] ^= 1 }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the operator I was looking for.

Comment: @steenslag, could you sort of explain it or link me to documentation? This looks like a cool concept and I want to understand it further. I tried the first couple links on google but it was just examples that I cant understand..

Comment: @Jeff, it's defined on the Fixnum class, but the docs are not helpful. XOR-ing with 1 is a well known bit flipping technique; added link to wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

```
def change_numbers(first_array, second_array)
  second_array.each { |index| first_array[index] = 1 - first_array[index] }
end
```

Comment: another work around method, would have never thought about it this way. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
def change_numbers(first_array, second_array)    
  second_array.each do |index| 
    first_array[index] = ((first_array[index] == 0) ? 1 : 0)
  end
end
```